# how can i make items on my base model for database immutable

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, pydantic

im trying to make the first two items immutable for they serve my database as natural keys, im trying to come up with a dynamic way that when these items get posted in my database they will not be changed

```
class Model(ItemModel):
    idNumber: str  #i want this immutable
    idrev: str        #and this too
    relState: str
    


repo = BaseRepository(db=get_dynamo_db(),
                      table_name=TABLE_NAME,
                      model=Model,
                      natural_keys=("idNumber","idrev"))
```

maybe i can do something where i am checking if they are not in the field name

```
    def __init__(self, db: ServiceResource, table_name: str, model: BaseModel, natural_keys: Tuple) -> None:
        self.db = db  # db resource will be injected when this repository is created in the main.py
        self.natural_keys = natural_keys

        table_exists = False
        for table_item in self.db.tables.all():

            if table_name == table_item.name:
                table_exists = True
                break

        self.table_name = table_name
        self.model = model

        self.field_names = list(model.__fields__.keys())
        for natural_key in natural_keys:
            if natural_key not in self.field_names:
                raise RuntimeError('natural keys not in model')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a mixture of AWS IAM and using [PartiQL for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.insert.html) to make your table append only.

In your code, do [an INSERT statement with PartiQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/example_dynamodb_ExecuteStatement_section.html), but deny "dynamodb:PartiQLUpdate”, "dynamodb:PartiQLDelete”, and all other DynamoDB API calls. DynamoDB won't let you do an INSERT statement using PartiQL for an existing primary key. "DuplicateItemException: Duplicate primary key exists in table". Here is [an example of such an IAM policy](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDBIAMPolicies/AmazonDynamoDBAppendOnlyAccess.json).